# Is there a metric version of this nomogram?

Tags: current, standard

I found this nomogram, which also appeared in an answer here I think.

[image]

(larger version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8dXP.png))

Is there a metric version of this?

Comment: Just for reference: [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5405/4950) is the answer, that explains how to use the nomogramm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the german book "Taschenbuch der Elektronik" you will find such a nomogramm on [page 641](http://books.google.de/books?id=RoMHm5EWDkoC&pg=PA641&lpg=PA641&dq=nomogramm+awg&source=bl&ots=AVd5RvbkoK&sig=vmRrfOrSlIbFdW-bgahee8VKRH4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=tu4sUMK0N8aztAblv4BI&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image: Nomogramm]

The axis are the same as in the version you provided.