# PCB Current Draw vs Temperature Rise Interpretation and Question

Tags: pcb-design, high-current

[I am using this tool for current calculation](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/)

While changing the input parameters i realized Temperature Rise °C is affecting the current draw.(you might say OF COURSE!)

At Ambient Temperature = 25°C

Temperature Rise = 10°C :
 50A current at 2oz copper at outer layer the required trace width is 33mm

Temperature Rise = 30°C :
 80A current at 2oz copper at outer layer the required trace width is 33mm

Does this mean that the **same amount of cooper in pcb (same trace width)** actually can handle and conduct higher 80A current but the pcb temperature will increase 30°C more as a cost. Is this correct.

If so do we need continuous amount of current draw to reach that temp rise. (If we draw 80A for short period of time like a peak does it still increase 30°C)

Comment: There are no units on your temperature measurements. Cut'n'paste these in as appropriate: °C, °F, K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the same amount of cooper in pcb (same trace width) actually can handle and conduct higher 80A current but the pcb temperature will increase 30°C more as a cost. Is this correct.

Yes.

- A trace will have a certain resistance and power dissipated will be given \$ P = I^2 R \$.
- Increasing the current by \$ \frac {80}{50} \$ will result in a heating power increase of \$ \frac {80^2}{50^2} = 2.56 \$ or 256%.
- It seems reasonable to assume that the final temperature rise would be 256% higher than that at 50 A but the vendor claims 300%.
- Equilibrium temperature will occur at the point where heat lost to the surroundings = electrical power into the resistance. Generally the higher the temperature difference the faster the outflow of heat. This again suggests that the 300% figure is higher than we would expect.
- The copper resistance has a positive temperature coefficient of +0.393%/°C. You can work out how much extra heat this will generate.
- Don't forget that with the resistance of the track comes a voltage drop proportional to the current.

> If so do we need continuous amount of current draw to reach that temp rise. (If we draw 80A for short period of time like a peak does it still increase 30°C.)

No. You could make an approximation based on the duty cycle for a < 1 s pulse (for example) but as the on-time gets long enough to be thermally significant you would want to assume the higher figure - a 10 s pulse for example.

See also: [Standard PCB trace widths?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5403/standard-pcb-trace-widths).

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer but you should wait until the Earth revolves at least once to give everyone a chance. You could well get better answers. Un-accept for a day or two.